# The installation of Workload Scheduler agent component fails during start up

Tags: installation, agent, workload-scheduler

The installation of Workload Scheduler agent component fails during the step **Start up IBM Workload Scheduler** showing the following message:

> **tebctl-tws_cpa_agent_agt94 agent not installed properly**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check that the installation directory has the proper permissions set. 
If you are installing in the /opt/IBM directory and its permissions are set to 750, change the permissions to 755.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can arise for one of the following three reasons:

1) your tws user "agt94" is not able to read the file "ita.ini" located in the "*TWS_HOME*/ITA/cpa/ita" folder;

2) your tws user "agt94" has not the needed execute permission on file "agent.sh" located in the "*TWS_HOME*/ITA/cpa/ita" folder;

3)  your tws user "agt94" has not the needed execute permission on file "agent" located in the "*TWS_HOME*/ITA/cpa/ita" folder.